# set field data = true on java elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, javaquery

Running a java elastic search query through Eclipse. Getting this error when I am testing it, and I can't find anywhere in the API that tells me how I can set this field data to true

> IllegalArgumentException[Fielddata is disabled on text fields by
>   default. Set fielddata=true on [created] in order to load fielddata in
>   memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however
>   use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I have recently encountered this issue but in my case, I faced this issue when I was performing the Sorting.

An Excerpt from the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html)

> Most fields are indexed by default, which makes them searchable. Sorting, aggregations, and accessing field values in scripts, however, requires a different access pattern from search.
>
> **Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default.**

we can solve this problem with two approaches

**1. Updating the mappings by enabling `fielddata` on `text` fields as `"fielddata": true`**

```
PUT your_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "my_field": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Appending `.keyword` to the field as `your_field.keyword` for aggregations, sorting.**

In the previous approach, we have to perform reindexing which is sometimes a cumbersome process for large indexes. For such cases, the below solution would be an easier solution to implement.

**ES Query:**

```
GET /your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
   "sort":[
      {
         "your_field.keyword":{
            "order":"asc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Java Code**

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("your_index");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
//Appending the .keyword to the sorting field
FieldSortBuilder fieldSortBuilder = SortBuilders.fieldSort("your_field"+".keyword");
fieldSortBuilder.order(SortOrder.ASC);
searchSourceBuilder.sort(fieldSortBuilder);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must modify index mapping properties:

```
try (XContentBuilder jsonBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()) {
    final XContentBuilder builder = jsonBuilder
            .startObject()
              .startObject("your_type")
                .startObject("properties")
                  .startObject("your_field")
                    .field("type", "text")
                    .field("fielddata", true)/*setting fielddata*/
                  .endObject()
                .endObject()
              .endObject()
            .endObject();

    client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("your_index")
            .setType("your_type")
            .setSource(builder)/*also there are overloads for setSource()*/
            .get();
}
```

**OR**

```
String source = "{\"your_type\":{\"properties\":{\"your_field\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"fielddata\":true}}}}";
client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("your_index)
        .setType("your_type")
        .setSource(source, XContentType.JSON)
        .get();
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "your_index": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "your_type": {
        "properties": {
          ...
          ...
          "your_field": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
          ...
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch 5.0, `String` fields were broken into two - `Text` and `Keyword`. If the property is supposed to be Analyzed, you'd want to migrate your `String` fields to `Text`, if not then migrate them to `Keyword`.

Look into your type mapping - If you had a property like this -

```
{
  "your_field": {
    "type" "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

You'd want to convert it to this -

```
{
  "your_field": {
    "type" "keyword",
    "index": true
  }
}
```

Similarly, if your property was supposed to be analyzed and you had it like this-

```
{
  "your_field": {
    "type" "string",
    "index": "analyzed"
  }
}
```

then you'd want to convert it to this-

```
{
  "your_field": {
    "type" "text",
    "index": true
  }
}
```

Details on [Elasticsearch official page](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)