# ElasticSearch Java API: Enabling fielddata on text fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have created an ElasticSearch index using the ElasticSearch Java API. Now I would like to perform some aggregations on data stored in this index, but I get the following error:

```
      "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [item] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
```

As suggested at this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_enabling_fielddata_on_literal_text_literal_fields), to solve this issue I should enable fielddata on the "item" text field, but how can I do that using the ElasticSearch Java API?

An alternative might be mapping the "item" field as a [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), but same question: how can I do that with the ElasticSearch Java API?

Comment: To map the field `item` as keyword, maybe try this: [Put Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-indices.html#java-admin-indices-put-mapping) (But only new indices created will respect this mapping)

Comment: Please check this answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47884701/1012497)

Answer (score 1):

For a new index you can set the mappings at creation time by doing something like:

```
CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
String source = // probably read the mapping from a file
createIndexRequest.source(source, XContentType.JSON);
restHighLevelClient.indices().create(createIndexRequest);
```

The mapping should have the same format as the request you can do against the rest endpoint similar to this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "your_property": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use XContentBuilder, easy to create json string to create or update mapping. It's seem like

```
.startObject("field's name")
    .field("type", "text")
    .field("fielddata", true)
.endObject()
```

After just use IndexRequest to create new indices or use PutMappingRequest to update old mapping

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered this issue but in my case, I faced this issue when I was performing the Sorting. I have posted a working solution for this problem in another similar question -> [set field data = true on java elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447205/set-field-data-true-on-java-elasticsearch/62269322#62269322)